# Where to store Soap XML in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, model-view-controller, soap

I have a rails App that sends large XML data files to a SOAP web service. Where should I store the XML files? I populate the XML using data stored in my database.
I currently have all the XML in my model and would like clean it up in a Rails way.

Update:

The flow basically works like this: A user registers for our service and provides personal identifying information. We take this information and 1. store in our database in our User table and 2. populate an XML that we then fire to our vendor in the form of a XML. We're currently populating the XML in the model that also creates the SOAP client. I am thinking of putting the XML in another view and using render_to_string, but want to run it by to community to see if it's a good idea.

The directory is fairly simple. The app is still in its early stages so we're still using the 6 default folders under the app folder.

Thanks for the questions and any suggestions.

Comment: You should provide more details, the directory structure for example.

Comment: And how do you know when to populate the XML? Cron job?